# Is there a way to disable certain parallel processes inside a step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

My scenario is as follows:

When an event occurs, several processes need to be executed in parallel.

A step function seems ideal for this:

e.g.

```
Event received:
- Parallel 1 - Send an SMS message
- Parallel 2 - Send an email
- Parallel 3 - Write data to a database
Gather all completed results to determine success / failure.
```

However, dependant on the type of event I may want to only execute a few of the processes.

An example would be: the incoming customer data does not contain an email address so we want to skip the email process.

Is there a way for the step function to enable, disable certain parallel processes dependant on the type of initial event?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to apply yes-no decision logic to each parallel branch:

1. Add a two-branch [Choice State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) at the start of each parallel branch. For instance, payloads matching `{"Variable": "$.email", "IsPresent": true}` continue to the `Parallel 2` branch, but otherwise bypass it.
2. Perform the parallel tasks in Lambdas using the SDKs. Use branching logic at the start of each Lambda to decide whether to process the payload.